# How to use VBA "Find" function to offset from the found cell

Tags: excel, vba, find, offset

I'm trying to offset from the cell returned by the Find function and then place a formula in that offset cell. The Find function works, I'm getting the first non-zero cell in the column of interest. What I'm having issues with is then offsetting from that cell which is in column X, over to column C. The column C cell is the one I need to change the formula of. Here is my code so far, please let me know of any help to achieve this.

```
Set lrow = Range("x33:x42").Find(What:="0", After:=Range("x33"), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
Set lrow = Range("lrow").Offset(0, -21).Select
```

I'm sure it's something to do with how the cell is stored from the Find function, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: `If Not lRow Is Nothing Then Set lrow = lrow.Offset(0, -21)` and then on the next line, `lRow.Select` - not sure why you are using the same variable tho.

Comment: Maybe you just mean: `lrow.Offset(0, -21).Select` ? You still need to check to make sure your `Find` actually returns something (if it found something) or you will get an error.

Comment: Another option would be something like `Set lrow = Range("C" & lrow.Row)` to avoid depending on the offset.

Comment: `lrow.EntireRow.Columns("C").Formula = ...`